# Generar un número al azar en un Scriplet y mostrarlo en un JSP como una etiqueta img

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

Como dice el título, tengo la siguiente duda:
Lo que quiero hacer es mostrar en un JSP una etiqueta `<img>` con *src=img/1.png* o *2.png* o *3.png* siendo que se genere este número al azar.
Se me había ocurrido generar un int random en un Scriplet con `Math.random()` y mostrarlo en la etiqueta con Expression Language, sin embargo, cuando ejecuto la aplicación web no se visualiza la imagen, y si visualizo el código fuente de la página se ve esto: `img src="img/.png" width="400"`

Dejo el código para que vean:

```
<section id="sec3">
<h1>Titulo</h1>
<div class="flexbox">
    <div class="caja">
        <%
            int numero = (int)(Math.random()*3+1);
        %>
        <img src="img/${numero}.png" width="400">
    </div>
    <div class="caja">
        <h2>Subtitulo</h2>
        <p><fmt:formatNumber value="${lugar.precio}" type="currency"/></p>
        <p>Texto</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola padaleiana, por las dudas te comento que ya lo resolví, igual muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya descubrí como se soluciona, lo pongo acá por si alguien tiene el mismo problema en un futuro:
Se solucionaba utilizando una expresión estándar de un JSP ( <%= %> ).
Dejo el código:

```
<section id="sec3">
<h1>Titulo</h1>
<div class="flexbox">
    <div class="caja">
        <%
            int numero = (int)(Math.random()*3+1);
        %>
        <img src="img/<%=numero%>.png" width="400">
    </div>
    <div class="caja">
        <h2>Subtitulo/h2>
        <p><fmt:formatNumber value="${lugar.precio}" type="currency"/></p>
        <p>Texto</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.